# My requests are not hitting to my breakpoint in Visual Studio after first trigger over swagger (.Net6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, breakpoints

When I am trying to trigger an action in my api application via swagger of my , my first request does hit my breakpoint on the code, but after first time it is not hitting no matter how many times I try to trigger.

[image: My code with breakpoint]

I am expecting my breakpoint to hit everytime I trigger the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

410 means this content is no longer available and will not be used. For this reason, browsers may exhibit caching behavior. Please delete the cache in your browser and try again.

If you are curious about the details, you can browse:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It really did worked. I was returning 410 status code for deleted ones, and 200 for active ones. And now I have tried an active one and the breakpoint is hitting every time I trigger. Then I have disabled cache on developer tools and now deleted one is hitting the breakpoint every time as well. Thank you so much!